# ngx-select - How to display custom items (different styles) in dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect, ng-content

I was trying to display the dropdown items using ngx-select with customized styling. The dropdown items are arrays of another components (with component specific styling). How to achieve this? Here is my code [selectDropdown](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngdropdown?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=editor)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the regular bootstrap styling? If so you need to add in your index.html before you ng node like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/optimistex/ngx-select-ex#styles-and-customization) as well it says for customization:

> Currently, the component contains CSS classes named within BEM Methodology. As well it contains the "Bootstrap classes". Recommended use BEM classes for style customization.

Comment: I meant the dropdown items should be a array of components (with specific template eg. the dropdown item should also have an icon, color, string) instead of just Strings. So that my dropdown component can be called at multiple locations with specific templates in the application. i.e. Drobdown 1 list's look and feel is different from dropdown 2 look and feel. @Lucho